# Error when using lists

Tags: r, list

I have .Rdata file with a list inside. However I get this error message when trying to display the list.

```
ls(data$Test$t0)

Error in list2env(list(c(2901, 4629, 3637, 5258, 4950, 4050, 3449, 8348,  : 
  names(x) must be a character vector of the same length as x
```

However this line of code works fine

```
ls(data$Test)
```

I don't understand how to fix this error. Any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: `ls()` returns the names of objects in your current environment. It's nothing to do with displaying lists.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! How should i display it then?

Comment: You can just type the name of the list, or its named elements. Or `str(data)` to see how it is structured.

Comment: @neilfws - well, not really - `ls(list(a=1,b=2))` for instance. I gather the issue is that `data$Test$t0` is not a recursive list object.

Comment: Well sure, that syntax works. But if I'd read `?ls` and `?names`, I'd go with the second one for that specific example. You're right about the recursive list issue.

Comment: Thanks both! The str(data) was useful.